# What would be the correct CSS selector be to use to hide plain text?

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I wanted to hide some text on my wesbite using CSS. I wanted to remove the "Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below." text on a users profile page. Please see image below.

When I inspect it, it shows like this:

https://prnt.sc/qskqbd

I wanted to use:

```
 display: none;
}
```

But I am not sure what the selector for this text would be as when I use:

```
<p>Your resume can be veiwed, edited or removed below.
</p> == $0
```

I get the following error:

https://prnt.sc/qskrgf

I was just wondering what the correct selector would be as I only wanted to hide this text only?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do with a crash course in [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) my friend.

`<p>Your resume can be veiwed, edited or removed below.</p> == $0` is the actual HTML, (and the `== $0`) is added by Dev Tools to show the currently selected element's index.

In order to select an element that doesn't have a dedicated class or id, you will need to select one of it's ancestors and then select it.

In your specific situation, you could use the following:

```
#resume-manager-candidate-dashboard > p {
    display: none;
}
```

What that does is selects the element with the `id="resume-manager-candidate-dashboard"`, then selects any `p` elements that are direct children, using the [`>` Direct Child Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator). I did this, because you could have a `p` in your table that just `#resume-manager-candidate-dashboard p` would also select.

Comment: hey thanks for this. I thought this would be a simple fix but I agree I could do with taking a course when I get a chance. Your solution worked great for me! Thanks again:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about how the work of **[Class and id](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp)**  :)

Now i'm come your real question, According to your image you need to set this property in your css file

```
#resume-manager-candidate-dashboard>p:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope it will help you. :)

Let me know if you have any further clarification.

Comment: thank you for this. This also worked great but I used another suggestion which was `#resume-manager-candidate-dashboard > p {
    display: none;
}`
Just wondering what the reason was to add the `:nth-child(1) {` at the end is?

Comment: When you add another `p` tag inside `#resume-manager-candidate-dashboard` than  you need to set 'nth-child' css. That's the main reason why i'm add `nth-child`, Make sure without `nth-child` selector is apply all the p tag inside  `#resume-manager-candidate-dashboard`. For more information you need to read this good article about [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) :)

Answer (score -1):

Add this css in your code the text hide automatically

```
p{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This will hide ALL `p` elements, not just the one that OP wants hidden. To hide just that one, he will need to select a targetable ancestor first.